# Mongodb $addToSet an object into nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongojs

I have tried to insert an object into an array inside another array which it only insert an empty object.

```
db.players.update({ username: crUserName }, { $addToSet: { finditem: nitem[0] } },{upsert:true} , function (err, doc)
```

nitem[0] is an object.

however, the result I found from the database is like this 
[image]

I have tried to insert value into this array , it worked but not with object.
I have done some research but I found nothing.

I hope someone here can help me! thanks.

===Updated===
Nitem[0] contain information of the item i want to put into the array "finditem".
It looks like this 
[image]

There is not err return for this, everytime I update, 
it says {ok:1, nModified:1, n:1}

Comment: Is there is anything in `err` object ? Print it add . Also add what `nitem[0]` contains . Add what they have in question .

Comment: Hi I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$addToSet doesn't compair whole object. this is not mongo feature currently. It's a little tricky. you can do it like somting

```
Player.findOneAndUpdate({
        username: crUserName,
        "finditem._id" : {$ne : nitem[0]._id }
    },
    {
        // addToSet insert if nitem _id not exists .
        $addToSet: {
            finditem: nitem[0]
        }
    },
    {
        upsert: false,
        new: true
    },(err, results)=>{
        console.log(err, results);
})
```

Comment: i am using Mongojs, so i assuming it will be findAndModify?

Comment: I tried, the result it return as What i need! However, When I query all players info. It still showing empty object under finditem array as I have put the picture above. Do you know any reason why?

Comment: make sure while test in mongo shell use .... {$ne :   ObjectId(nitem[0]._id) }  and test with a new record so debug can easy

Comment: I found the problem which related to another issue. thanks for the answer.